# Examples of indefinite Einstein non-Ricci-flat metric on solvmanifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebras, compactness, semi-riemannian-geometry, kahler-einstein-metric

A solvmanifold (resp. nilmanifold) is a compact quotient of a solvable (risp. nilpotent) Lie group $G$. Usually one consider a co-compact lactice $\Gamma$ on $G$ and the solvmanifold is $G/\Gamma$. Moreover, if there are left-invariant structures on $G$ (e.g. metrics, complex strucutres etc.), those structures define analogous structure on the compact quotient. Moreover, left-invariant structures are viewed as tensors on the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$.

I would like to know if there are known examples of solvmanifold with pseudo-Riemannian (or semi-Riemannian or indefinite) Einstein non-Ricci-flat metrics.

By the previous discussion, this question can be rephrase as follows: Are there examples of solvable Lie algebras admitting indefinite metrics (i.e. indefinite non-degenerate bilinear form) which are Einstein non-ricci-flat? Do those examples admit compact quotients?

Finally, remind that a nilpotent Lie group is a solvable Lie group, and a result of Maltcev assure that nilpotent Lie group with rational constant structures admits a co-compact lactice (hence a compact quotient).

Comment: Crossposted on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4091357/examples-of-indefinite-einstein-non-ricci-flat-metric-on-solvmanifolds) and stackexchange [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/626660/examples-of-indefinite-einstein-non-ricci-flat-metric-on-solvmanifolds).

Comment: @DietrichBurde True, but nobody answer yet. I will delete those post, keeping this one

Comment: What about Conti's [article](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/forum-2020-0049/html)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde that article seems a good reference, as far as I understand it deals with nilpotent Lie algebras (which admits compact quotients). Are you aware of something similar on non-nilpotent solvable Lie algebras? 
In any case, this is a good answer to my question, so I will accept it if you answer. Thank you.